# How can I stop tkinter from outputting "[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction" on Mac?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am using Python v.3.10.7 and tkinter to open a file dialog, and I believe this to be an issue specific to MacOS (using 13.0 (22A380)), however when I am running the following:

```
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

file = fd.askopenfilename()
print(file)
```

The console returns the following when the dialog box is opened:

> 2022-11-14 20:54:12.497 Python[10059:11543274] +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction

Just wondering if there is anyway to stop these from being returned- I have also noticed that when moving the dialog box, the line gets spammed constantly.

Comment: using macOS 13.1 Ventura, python 3.8 : getting the same in pyqt6 within `QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory`

Comment: Using macOS 13.2, Python 3.10, and tkinter 8.6.12, getting the same issue with `filedialog.askdirectory`

Comment: macOS Ventura 13.1, Python 3.11, reproduced.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it is a [bug](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/722889) that arose in macOS Ventura (13.0+).

The bug arises from [NSOpenPanel](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsopenpanel), the builtin API for creating file dialogs, and throws a message straight to the stderr of the process.

Bug reports were opened in multiple languages, among them [Python](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/101895), but it is up to Apple to fix it.

You can attempt a workaround by changing the default stderr of the Python executable and filtering those messages out, but frankly I'd just leave it as is.

Comment: [Java equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75920986/1658617).

Comment: How do I change the default stderr of the Python executable?

Comment: @digitalguy99 usually using commandline piping and sending the stderr somewhere else. Keep in mind it will remove all of the stderr that comes out of your program including logging, exceptions etc. I highly discourage against doing so.