# "java[934:22850] +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction" when a FileChooser dialog box is displayed

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx

In running a Java program, using IntelliJ Community Edition 2021.2, I am seeing console output "java[934:22850] +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction" when a FileChooser dialog box is displayed. The dialog appears to work OK, but I'm puzzled about the message.

MacOS 13.0.1 (Ventura);
IntelliJ Community Edition 2021.2;
JDK 15.0.2;
JavaFX 15.0.1+1

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.*;

public class Main extends Application {

    // ..................... and now it's time for the main routine .....................

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // we need a FileChooser
        FileChooser myChooser = new FileChooser();

        // set up a controlled exit
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
            e.consume();
            primaryStage.close();
        });

        // define the main scene's building blocks
        VBox root = new VBox(5); // the spacing is between each element in the VBox
        Scene mainScene = new Scene(root, 650, 300);

        // just one button in the scene
        Button websiteSupportButton = new Button("Process file");
        websiteSupportButton.setMinWidth(150);
        root.getChildren().add(websiteSupportButton);
        websiteSupportButton.setOnAction(e -> processFiles(primaryStage, myChooser));

        // and now we're ready to associate the root Scene with the primary stage, and show it
        primaryStage.setX(20);
        primaryStage.setY(20);
        primaryStage.setScene(mainScene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Error test");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    // .................................. tool scenes ..................................

    // stuff moved from WebsiteSupport, and severely cut down - select an input file.
    private static void processFiles(Stage myStage, FileChooser myChooser) {
        File inputFile;

        // need to select an input file - displaying this dialog causes multiple "java[1334:69043] +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction" messages
        inputFile = myChooser.showOpenDialog(myStage);
        if (inputFile != null) {
            System.out.println(" file processed");
        }
    }

    // .......................................... standard stuff ..........................................

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried making the file chooser local, and get the same problem; next up, upgrade the JDK and JavaFX. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in MacOS Ventura, [unrelated to Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75540727/1658617), which occurs on `showOpenDialog`.

A bug report was opened for Apple, waiting for them to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code on:

- OS X (intel) 13.0.1
- JavaFX 19
- OpenJDK 19.0.1

It received the same error message (multiple times for a single call):

```
java[34308:361725] +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction
```

I believe it occurs every time the file chooser `showOpenDialog` method is invoked in this configuration.  A minimal example which replicates the issue on execution is:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FileChooserCATransactionLogGeneratorApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(new Group()));
        stage.show();

        FileChooser myChooser = new FileChooser();
        myChooser.showOpenDialog(stage);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I advise filing a [bug report](https://wiki.openjdk.org/display/OpenJFX/Submitting+a+Bug+Report).

If you do file a bug report and a bug id is generated, you can add a link to the bug report as a comment or an edit on this answer.

Comment: For reference, this appears to be a regression from JavaFX 17.

Comment: Bug report https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8299489 has been raised.