# Why does FileChooser output errors in console? How do I supress them?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, console

Whenever I invoke FileChooser's showOpenDialog() method in JavaFX:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();
        File file = chooser.showOpenDialog(stage);
    }
}
```

I get these console messages in red:

> 2022-12-27 20:41:49.955 java[75677:2827731] +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction

> 2022-12-27 20:41:50.093 java[75677:2827731] +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction

[image: error message]

I tried looking up the problem online but there were only two search hits and they didn't contain a solution. The one on here mentioned something about a bug in JavaFX, but I've faced the same issue even with JavaFX-11 and now with JavaFX-19.

Please note that the method works fine. I just don't want the messages to be output.

Does anybody have an idea what this message means, why it appears, and how to supress it?

Thanks.

Comment: [mcve] please .. and no screenshots of plain text

Comment: @kleopatra Although my question was pretty clear & the problem easy to reproduce, I just simplified the screenshot and added a code snippet. A simple 'Ctrl + C' will work. Is this what you meant?

Comment: No ... sorry ... that is NOT what we mean.  Read the link carefully and you will understand what we mean by "minimal reproducible example" ... and why we are asking you to do this.

Comment: As this may "be a regression from JavaFX 17", cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74882839/230513), try reverting to an earlier version.

Comment: @StephenC I've just replaced the example with a minimal reproducible one. Let me know if I got it wrong.

Comment: @trashgod What do you mean by "regression from JavaFX 17"?

Comment: These warnings/errors you're seeing printed to the console are not your fault. The problem seems to be with how JavaFX interacts with the operating system. In other words, this looks to be a bug in JavaFX itself. Which unfortunately means you probably can't do anything about it except wait for a fix to be released.

Comment: Though it [seems like no bug report exists for this yet](https://bugs.openjdk.org/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20JDK%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20Unresolved%20AND%20component%20%3D%20javafx%20AND%20text%20~%20%22called%20within%20transaction%22%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC%2C%20updated%20DESC). Perhaps you could [submit one](https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/).

Comment: There is an internal problem with the javafx SDK, the statement should not be displayed to the user.